# SQLLITE/ Android Studio Update Function Not Working

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

so I'm having some trouble with SQLLite/Android studio, I have an activity that lets me update a user's password through an SQLLite function but it doesn't seem to be working, when I press the update password button, nothing happens, and the database doesn't update.

SQLLITE Update:

```
  public int updateShopper(Shopper shopper)
        {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COL_SPPASS, shopper.getShopperPS());
            String[] l = {shopper.getShopperID()+""};


            return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_SPID + " =? ",l);

        }
```

Get all shoppers :

```
  public ArrayList<Shopper> getAllShoppers()
        {
            ArrayList splist = new ArrayList();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {
                    Shopper shopper = new Shopper();
                    shopper.setShopperUN(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(COL_SPNAME))));
                    shopper.setShopperPS(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_SPPASS)));

                    splist.add(shopper);
                } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            return splist;
        }

    }
```

Activity Button :

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username = ed1.getText().toString();
                String password = ed2.getText().toString();

                SQLShop sqlsp2 = new SQLShop(getApplicationContext());

                ArrayList splist=sqlsp2.getAllShoppers();
                for(int i=0;i<splist.size();i++)
                {
                    Shopper sp=(Shopper) splist.get(i);

                    if(username.equalsIgnoreCase(sp.getShopperUN()))
                    {
                        Shopper shopper  = new Shopper();
                        shopper.setShopperUN(username);
                        shopper.setShopperPS(password);
                        shopper.setShopperID(shopper.getShopperID());
                        sqlsp2.updateShopper(shopper);

                        break;
                    }

                }

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);



            }
        });
```

Comment: run this step-by-step through a debugger, the issue will be obvious

Comment: Sorry still a bit new to android studio, how do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/

Comment: I might be an idiot ( I am actually) but none of the stuff in the debugger seems to show any issue.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on this line `return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COL_SPID + " =? ",l);`, you'll see that, as laalto indicated, the value of the id you're querying is `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getAllShoppers()` you're not setting the shopper id and it remains as 0. Trying to update a row with id 0 matches no rows, so no rows are updated.

After adding reading the shopper id from the database, fix this part too:

> ```
> shopper.setShopperID(shopper.getShopperID());
> ```

Here you're assigning the id of a new `Shopper` back to itself so it stays as 0 default value. Change `shopper.getShopperID()` to `sp.getShopperID()`.

Comment: I added                                         shopper.setShopperID(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(COL_SPID)))); to the SQL, but it doesn't seem like anything changed

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful explanations! Greatly Appreciated!